# Debugger in CLion on Macos Ventura not working

Tags: macos, cmake, clion, lldb, macos-ventura

CLion 2022.2.4, Bundled cmake 3.23.3, Bundled lldb 14.0.6, Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102), macOS ventura 13.0.

Since I updated the system, the debugger does not hit breakpoints anymore. The breakpoint turns gray, the tooltip says "No executable code is associated with this line".

The project is a regular project with a shared library. All default (debug, no optimizations). Everything worked fine until the update. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a day or two I found out that this is indeed a bug in CLion. There is an open [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-30128/LLDB-doesnt-work-on-mac-os-13-Ventura) for it.

Users there report that the issue is solved in the [CLion Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/clion/nextversion/) build.